# Displaying Scenario with questions and choices

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on an web application which is like a quiz module. but instead of displaying one question at a time, there will be a scenario first and after that scenario there will be a multiple questions regarding with that scenario.

it is like this.

First will be the scenario question

[image]

then after the scenario it will look like this, there will be always 3 question per scenario.

[image]

I can already get the data, but i am really having a hard time on how can i display it.

Scenario Table

```
scenario_id |      scenario
   1           Sample Scenario 1
   2           Sample Scenario 2
   3           Sample Scenario 3
```

that is my table for the scenario.

then for the question and choice it look like this.

Question Table

```
question_id  | scenario_id| question
    1              1         sample question scenario 1.1
    2              1         sample question scenario 1.2
    3              1         sample question scenario 1.3
    4              2         sample question scenario 2.1
    5              2         sample question scenario 2.2
    6              2         sample question scenario 2.3
```

Choices table

```
choice_id |  question_id |  | choices
1                 1             choices 1 for question_id 1.1
2                 1             choices 1 for question_id 1.1
3                 1             choices 1 for question_id 1.1
4                 1             choices 1 for question_id 1.1
```

what i have right now is:

ScenarioController

```
  public function scenario(Request $request)
  {
     $scenarios = User_set::select(
       'component.scenario_id',
       'scenario.component AS scenario'
     )
     ->from('user_set AS user')
     ->leftJoin('scenarios AS scenario', 'scenario.id', '=', 'component.scenario_id')
     ->where('user.user_id',Auth::user()->id)
     ->inRandomOrder()
     ->get()
     ->toArray();

     return response()->json([
       'scenarios'=>$scenarios,
       'success'=>'Success'
    ]);
  }
```

Can anyone help me on how can i start displaying my Scenarios then it will go to question for that scenario in my view? I am really having a hardtime to analyze my problem. getting the data on my tables is easy for me but i just don't know on how can i display it on my view.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would include retrieving the current set of questions that i need using AJAX or making 1 request with AJAX In the beginning of the quiz taking all questions.

These questions would be saved on an array and would look like the database structure.

Then:

1. Keep the counter of the current scenario set (default 0 in the start) and bind a click event listener to a button.
   2 When the button is triggered you can generate the questions using javascript on the screen. You will get the current questions by filtering the array based on the current question set.
2. When the user inputs an answer you can modify the array with the questions to show which answer the user has input.
3. If the user now goes back and forth in the question sets he will still see the answer that he input because it has been saved in the array with the objects.